# iOS App rejection with a reason - ' The Auto Screen lock feature of your app functions with or without the featured enabled within the app settings'

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have submitted an iOS timer based app for review last week and today Apple rejected it saying the following reason,

2.2 - Apps that exhibit bugs will be rejected
2.2 Details

We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad running iOS 9.0.2 and iPhone running iOS 9.0.2 on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks.

- The Auto Screen lock feature of your app functions with or without the featured enabled within the app settings.

Like many other timer based apps (or pomodoro apps) available in the app store, I have included toggle function in my application whether a user can enable or disable auto screen lock when the app is on foreground. It works as intended, prevent screen locks only when the app is in the foreground. All other time screen lock is working based on Auto-Lock status in the settings App.

These are the code I have used, In the Main view controller, when the view loads,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
//...
    NSNumber *screenLockStatus = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kFLScreenLockKey];

    if (!screenLockStatus) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:NO];
    } else {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:[screenLockStatus boolValue]];
    }
}
```

Then in the settings view controller of the app,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{ //....
    self.preventScreenLockSwitch.on = [UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled; 
}

- (IBAction)preventScreenLock:(UISwitch *)sender
{
    // Disable idle timer to prevent screen lock while app is on foreground.
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:self.preventScreenLockSwitch.isOn];

    // Save Screenlock prevent switch status.
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:self.preventScreenLockSwitch.isOn] forKey:kFLScreenLockKey];
    [userDefaults synchronize];
}
```

I have tested it on many devices and it works as intended. I am not really sure whether the reviewer got it wrong or is there something wrong with this approach.

Has anyone faced this situation earlier? If so what is the recommended solution?

Appreciate any help on this matter.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you use the user defaults to enable/disable screen lock when the app launches ?

Comment: Yes. I use it to set idleTimeDisabled to YES or NO based on the user preference. The code I used in my app is given above.

Comment: Where?  I can't see any code that sets the idle timer on app start?

Comment: " The Auto Screen lock feature of your app functions with or without the featured enabled within the app settings."  This is the reason they provided, which is kind of confusing to me. In all the tests ( done it on 4 devices. iPad Air 2, iPhone 5S, 6 and 6+ three of them running iOS 9.0.2) it gets enabled only if the user enables it.